# Update if exist else insert not working

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, procedure

I need help regarding a SQL procedure. I have tried and done every way I can but the below procedure didn't work, Need help why it's not working,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser
     (IN ID INT(11), 
      name VARCHAR(100), 
      email VARCHAR(100), 
      role VARCHAR(9), 
      gender VARCHAR(6), 
      birthday VARCHAR(10), 
      classroom INT(11) )  

   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

   BEGIN TRANSACTION;
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE userID = ID)
       BEGIN
           UPDATE tbl_users 
           SET userName = name, userEmail = email, userRole = role, 
               gender = gender, birthday = birthday 
           WHERE userID = ID;

           UPDATE student 
           SET classID = classroom 
           WHERE userID = ID;
       END
       ELSE
       BEGIN
           UPDATE tbl_users 
           SET userName = name, userEmail = email, userRole = role, 
               gender = gender, birthday = birthday 
           WHERE userID = ID;

           INSERT INTO student(classID, userID) 
           VALUES (classroom, ID);
       END

       COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Above update into student query and insert into query both work individually. But not when `IF EXISTS` is inserted.

Comment: What you mean isnt working? Any error? Wrong behaviour?

Comment: Clarify your question please.

Comment: Data not being inserted or updated in the database

Comment: When I try to update the student table without using the if statement it works. But when I use the if statement it does not work.

Comment: No error msg is returning and no data is being inserted. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Is this sql server?

Comment: Im using xampp, PHP, mysqli

Comment: I cant see where is the problem. My suggestion do some debugging. Test if the `EXISTS` is working properly with some print messages. Remove the transaction. Start with something basic and builds up until you see where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL. Try the below code and see whether it works,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateUser
     (IN ID INT(11), 
      name VARCHAR(100), 
      email VARCHAR(100), 
      role VARCHAR(9), 
      gender VARCHAR(6), 
      birthday VARCHAR(10), 
      classroom INT(11) )  


   BEGIN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM student WHERE userID = ID) THEN
       START TRANSACTION;
           UPDATE tbl_users 
           SET userName = name, userEmail = email, userRole = role, 
               gender = gender, birthday = birthday 
           WHERE userID = ID;

           UPDATE student 
           SET classID = classroom 
           WHERE userID = ID;
       COMMIT;
       ELSE
       START TRANSACTION;
           UPDATE tbl_users 
           SET userName = name, userEmail = email, userRole = role, 
               gender = gender, birthday = birthday 
           WHERE userID = ID;

           INSERT INTO student(classID, userID) 
           VALUES (classroom, ID);

       COMMIT;
       END IF;
   END;
```